# How to use std::move() to move char[] to a vector<char>

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to concatenate two char arrays `char a[9000]; char b[9000]` to a container `std::vector<char>`. Since the array size is not small. I am trying to use `std::move()`

```
class obj
{
public:
obj &operator <<(char *&&ptr)
        {
            //???
            ptr = nullptr;
            return *this;
        }
private:
    std::vector<char> m_obj;
};
```

So in the main function

```
int main()
{
    obj o;
    enum {SIZE=9000};
    char a[SIZE]; memset(a, 1, SIZE);
    char b[SIZE]; memset(b, 2, SIZE);
    o << a << b;
    return 0;
}
```

My question is what is the correct way to move a char*?

---

**Environment**:
Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
g++ 5.4.0

Comment: A `char*` is a trivial object (it's typically 8 bytes). You won't gain anything from moving it.

Comment: Simple answer: don't, use a `std::string` instead.

Comment: `move` doesn't actually move anything. And 9000 `char`s is a very small amount that's nothing to worry about.

Comment: You can't move a stack-allocated array into a heap object. That makes no sense. (What would you expect to happen when the stack-allocated array goes out of scope?)

Comment: You cannot move a `char*` to a `char[]` or to a `vector<char>`, they are completely diffetent things. Moving primitive data types is exactly the same as copying. You can use `memcpy` or `memmove` to copy characters from one array to another, though generally you shouldn't. Use std::string instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Call `reserve()` and copy.

#### What's wrong with moving?

Several things. First, the expectation that you seem to have about `std::move` is wrong. `std::move` does not magically move anything (or moves anything at all, including non-magically). What it does is a cast to a rvalue reference, which may *enable* moving under some conditions.

Second, beginning with C++03, `std::vector` is *guaranteed* to have its element contiguously laid out in memory (before C++03 it was factually the case anyway, but no explicit guarantee was given). If you use `std::move` then you necessarily use a version later than C++03, so `std::vector` necessarily lays out its elements contiguously.
Which means that except for the totally coincidal case that the two arrays *happen to be* adjacent to each other, there is no way of getting the elements from two arrays into a vector without copying. It's simply not possible to move them because *at least* one array must be relocated (= copied).

Further, I couldn't imagine how moving elements from an array the way you intend to do it would be possible in the first place. Moving assumes that you take over ownership, which usually means you modify the moved-from object in some way so that it is still valid, but without whatever resources it owned previously.
How do you do that with an array that has automatic storage duration in a surrounding scope? What is dereferencing the array after the move (which is possible and legitimate) going to do then?

Also, you want to decay an array to a pointer (that's perfectly legal) and then somehow magically move. That, however, does not move the contents of the array! The best you can do is move the pointer, but that doesn't make sense since moving a pointer is just the same as copying it.

There is no way you're getting around having to copy the array elements, but you can save one memory allocation and one needless copy by properly calling `reserve()` ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, char* isn't exactly object you want to move. So, getting rvalue reference to the pointer won't exactly help.
Why don't you try array-like way of moving and use std::move from "algorithm"?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move

It'd look something like that:

```
obj& obj::addChars(char *ptr, size_t size = 9000u) {    
    m_obj.resize(size);
    std::move(ptr, ptr + size, m_obj.begin());
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: `m_obj` needs to be appropriately sized for this to work.  Might want to use a `back_inserter` instead.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not sure about it, but it seems like resizing vector once(if you know the number of elements you need) is better then putting elements one by one, because then there are no need of moving data once its to big to already allocated inner array. But I can be mistaking inner structure of std::vector.

Comment: That's an illegal signature for `operator<<` (only allowed one argument).

Comment: "An object is a region of storage" (The Standard).

Comment: @John you can use `reserve` first

Comment: @n.m. and `char*` is a pointer to the first `object` of type `char` in given array.

Comment: Yes, it is also an object.

Comment: @n.m. what is the difference between `resize` + `move to begin` and `reserve` + `move each element to the back (using iterator)` ?

Comment: @n.m. all right, it is, but I don't see why would somebody try moving object, storing address of other one. It's 4/8 bytes, anyway. Even 1000 copies won't harm.

Comment: @JohnCvelth moving an object is a way of copying it. Moving an object of fundamental type is exactly the same as copying. So, moving a `char*` is copying. Just like moving a `char` is copying. I would use `std::copy` here to not confuse the reader of the code.

Comment: @user2079303 using `std::move` you explicitly allow to do what-ever-is-better-for-quicker-copying with the data (including corrupting). That's the fundamental difference between `copy` and `move`. Who know what effect it will really have but it won't make matters worse, will it?

Answer (score 1):

The following works because a vector is contiguous memory.
It is necessary to resize the vector to hold the amount of elements being copied.

&vc[0] is the memory address of the 0th element of the vector.
&vc[SIZE] is the memory address of the 9000th element of the vector, which is where array b should start.

This will execute much faster than trying to iterate through the arrays and push_back, or assign the vector elements.

```
enum {SIZE=9000};
char a[SIZE];
memset(a, 1, SIZE);

char b[SIZE];
memset(b, 2, SIZE);

// make a vector of characters
std::vector<char> vc;
// resize to hold two arrays
vc.resize(SIZE * 2);

// copy array a to the beginning of the vector
memcpy(&vc[0], a, SIZE);
// copy array b to the end of the vector
memcpy(&vc[SIZE], b, SIZE);
```

edit:

```
std::vector<char> vc(SIZE * 2);
```

is the same as create, then resize.  It will create the vector with the specified size, then the resize is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you allocated the arrays using `new` there is no way to get vector to adopt the arrays. A copy will take place.

The recommended approach is `std::copy` which in most implementations will be recognized as optimizable to a `std::memcpy()`.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#define SIZE 90

int main(void) {
    std::vector<char> v;
    v.resize(2*SIZE);

    char a[SIZE]; 
    char b[SIZE]; 

    std::memset(a, 'a', SIZE);
    std::memset(b, 'b', SIZE);

    std::copy(a,a+SIZE,v.begin());
    std::copy(b,b+SIZE,v.begin()+SIZE);

    for(char c : v){
        std::cout << c;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If it isn't so optimized (unlikely), use a `std::memcpy()`.

How you implement that in you class is another debate.
You could implement an `add(char *start,char *end);` member.

As others point out 9000 `char` isn't huge and you might be over-engineering if you do more.

A further extension would allow you to `resize()` or `reserve()` size in the vector to avoid an inevitable resize during the second copy.