# What is the efficient way to add a std::string to a STL container with a value of a c-str buffer in memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14, move-semantics

Let's say I have a buffer of chars in memory that holds a c_string, and I want to add an object of `std::string` with the content of that c_string to a standard container, such as `std::list<std::string>`, in an efficient way.

Example:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> list;

    char c_string_buffer[] {"For example"};

    list.push_back(c_string_buffer); // 1

    list.emplace_back(c_string_buffer); // 2

    list.push_back(std::move(std::string(c_string_buffer))); // 3
}
```

I use ReSharper C++, and it complains about #1 (and suggests #2).

When I read [push_back vs emplace_back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/), it says that when it is not an rvalue, the container will store a "copied" copy, not a moved copy. Meaning, #2 does the same as #1. [Don’t blindly prefer emplace_back to push_back](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/03/03/push-back-emplace-back/) also talks about that.

Case 3: When I read [What's wrong with moving?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45617335/65863), it says that what `std::move()` does "is a cast to a rvalue reference, which may enable moving **under some conditions**".

--

Does #3 actually give any benefit? I assume that the constructor of `std::string` is called and creates a `std::string` object with the content of the c_string. I am not sure if later the container constructs another `std::string` and copies the 1st object to the 2nd object.

Comment: The first link talks about a faulty implementation of `emplace_back` in an older version of MSVC. In the current version it correctly constructs a new `std::string` in place

Comment: for 3, `std::move` is not necessary, a temporary is already an r-value

Comment: you could try it and and see what the difference is, it would be interesting to see

Comment: Did you actually read the article you cited? It isn’t saying don’t use emplace, it’s saying the students didn’t fully understand how to take advantage of the suggestion and that the tooling didn’t catch the issue after they tried to implement its suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`// 3` is fully equivalent to `// 1`. `std::move` does absolutely nothing here since `std::string(c_string_buffer)` is already a rvalue.

The problem with `push_back` is not related to move vs copy.

`push_back` is always a bad choice if you don't yet have an object of the element type because it always creates the new container element via copy or move construction from another object of the element type.

If you write `list.push_back(c_string_buffer); // 1`, then because `push_back` expects a `std::string&&` argument (or `const std::string&`), a temporary object of type `std::string` will be constructed from `c_string_buffer` and passed-by-reference to `push_back`. `push_back` then constructs the new element from this temporary.

With `// 3` you are just making the temporary construction that would otherwise happen implicitly explicit.

The second step above can be avoided completely by `emplace_back`. Instead of taking a reference to an object of the target type, it takes arbitrary arguments by-reference and then constructs the new element directly from the arguments. No temporary `std::string` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

> Does 3 actually give any benefit?

No. #1 already does a move without `std::move`. #3 is just an unnecessarily explicit way to write #1.

#2 is *generally* potentially most efficient. That's why your static analyzer suggests it. But, as the article explains, it's not significant in this case, and has a potential compile-time penalty. I believe you can avoid the potential compile-time cost by using `list.emplace_back(+c_string_buffer);`, but that may be confusing to the reader.